can a \gategroup box have two labels?
I'm trying to place labels both above and below a single \gategroup box in my circuit, but haven't been able to figure it out, nor find examples on line. For instance:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
\gategroup[4,steps=6,style={dotted, cap=round, inner sep=7pt}]{label 1, label 2}
\push{x_2}
  & 
  & 
  & 
  & \ctrl{3} 
  & 
\\
\push{x_1}
  & 
  & \ctrl{2}
  & 
  & 
  &
\\
\push{x_0}
  & \ctrl{1}
  & 
  & 
  & 
  &
\\
 \lstick{$y$}
  & \targ{} 
  & \targ{} 
  & 
  & \targ{} 
  &
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}

I'd like "label 1" above the box, "label 2" below.  Suggestions?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show a minimal working example of your code.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

apologies!  is this better?

Yes! Thank you for editing.

I would just add the second label using the standard tikz syntax and include it in the style options.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
\gategroup[4,steps=6,style={dotted, cap=round, inner sep=7pt,label=below:label 2}]{label 1}
\push{x_2}
  & 
  & 
  & 
  & \ctrl{3} 
  & 
\\
\push{x_1}
  & 
  & \ctrl{2}
  & 
  & 
  &
\\
\push{x_0}
  & \ctrl{1}
  & 
  & 
  & 
  &
\\
 \lstick{$y$}
  & \targ{} 
  & \targ{} 
  & 
  & \targ{} 
  &
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}

